# heroku run python manage.py migrate -> No module named production

Tags: python, django, heroku, migration

I am new to python/django and need some help.

Currently, I am working on a book called hellowebapp and came across a problem during heroku deployment. When I type "heroku run python manage.py migrate", I get this message :

[the screen shot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jHjC.png)

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ ryujihellowebapp... up, run.4755 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named production
```

How can I fix the last part ? :

```
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named production
```

Also, when I type 'heroku open' and open the application in a browser, there is a message that says "Application Error". Everything works fine with no error message in localhost and seems like there was no issue I pushed the app to heroku. As soon as I started to work on the heroku migration part, the problem started to occur.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out your build log on `heroku` dash board so you can see why your application is showing *Application Error*, further more try run `heroku run python your_project_core_folder_name/manage.py makemigrations` then migrate, you need to be more specific about it

Comment: @ Svekar Ok, so I managed to do migration, but it's still showing me an error message when I open the app in a browser. I am not sure where I can find build logs on heroku dash board. Is that the same thing as heroku logs? If so, this is what it says :  ValueError: The file 'css/style.css' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7ff8f01577d0>.

Comment: It's the same thing, I can just guess that your `whitenoise` is not configured properly, so it's messing with your static assets, here is `whitenoise` docs, try inspect your configuration http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html